# JSHint options do not apply (Sublime3)

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint

I've installed SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-jshint and JSHint itself works. However, i'm not able to configure JSHint. I tried to add jshint settings to SublimeLinter.sublime-settings but it seems that there is no effect on JSHint.
This is what my settings (Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings - User) look like:

```
{
"user": {
    "debug": false,
    "delay": 0.25,
    "error_color": "D02000",
    "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
    "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
    "lint_mode": "background",
    "linters": {
        "jshint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": [],
            "maxdepth": 1,
            "strict": "global",
            "sub": true
        }
    },
    "mark_style": "outline",
    "no_column_highlights_line": false,
    "passive_warnings": false,
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "python_paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "rc_search_limit": 3,
    "shell_timeout": 10,
    "show_errors_on_save": false,
    "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
    "syntax_map": {
        "html (django)": "html",
        "html (rails)": "html",
        "html 5": "html",
        "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
        "magicpython": "python",
        "php": "html",
        "python django": "python",
        "pythonimproved": "python"
    },
    "warning_color": "DDB700",
    "wrap_find": true
}
}
```

I've added some example settings like '"maxdepth": 1', but these rules do not apply. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Settings](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint#settings) section of the README on Github, also available on the [Package Control page](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint):

> You can configure `jshint` options in the way you would from the command line, with `.jshintrc` files. For more information, see the [jshint docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/). The linter plugin does this by searching for a `.jshintrc` file [...]

Read the full section and the linked docs for all the directions, then place a `.jshintrc` file where appropriate for your project.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read that section but i was a bit confused. First, i didn't know that you actually have to call the file ".jshintrc" instead of something like "FILENAME.jshintrc".
Do you know if it is possible to go by the way i've mentioned in my first post (via sublime user settings)?

Comment: @rinderwahn No, I don't think it's possible.